# How to get auto end date based on selection of start date and no. of days of travel

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am new with Django and coding. After doing Local Library and Polls tutorial on MDN and Django respectively.
I am now working on travel itinerary app. Where I want that my model should be able to take start date as enter by user and based on number of nights selected by user should auto fill the end date.

Example:
Start Date: 09-July-21
No. of Nights: 05
End Date: 14-July-21

Code for models.py is as follows, I will be using Postgresql DB for this project

```
class Packages(models.Model):
    title_package = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    no_of_nights = models.SmallIntegerField()
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    start_date = models.DateField(help_text='should not allow client to book in past')
    end_date = models.DateField(help_text='based on start date selection and no. of nights client is staying.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count end date on view form_valid as follows:

```
def form_valid(self, form):

    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    
    start_date = form.cleaned_data.get('start_date')
    no_of_nights = form.cleaned_data.get('no_of_nights')
    
    instance.end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=no_of_nights)
    
    instance.save()
```